# Replacing/Changing one value of an array with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array that is created within another Javascript call.  The array is as follows:

```
 HM_Array1 = [[,11,147,,,,,,,1,1,0,0,0,1,"csiSetBorder(this)","null",,,true,["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Accoun&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","",1,0,1],["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Resources&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","",1,0,1],["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reworking&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","",1,0,1],["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Account Services&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","",1,0,1],["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Education&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","",1,0,1],["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; App&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;","",1,0,1]];
```

I am trying to replace just the '147' value at the top if another element is present within the HTML. So far I haven't had any luck.

This is the code I have been working with thus far.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

if ($('#impersonationWrapper').length > 0) {
    var arr = HM_Array1;
    var valChange = HM_Array1[0][2];
    if (valChange !== -1) {
        HM_array[valChange] = 202;
    }

    }
    else {

    }
});
```

The 147 corresponds to the value of the CSS 'top' value.  Unfortunately I have to change this dynamically as I am not allowed to touch the old coding in place.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
var valChange = HM_Array1[0][2];
if (valChange !== -1) {
    HM_Array1[0][2] = 202;
}
```

Your code

```
HM_array[valChange] = 202;
```

is the same as:

```
HM_array[HM_Array1[0][2]] = 202;
```

which is:

```
HM_array[147] = 202;
```

which is setting the value of the 147th item in `HM_array` as `202`. Which isn't what you want. `HM_array` has only 1 item. And you want to set that item's 2nd item as `202` (replace `147` with `202`).

Comment: That did it.  I don't know how I overlooked that.  Thank you! I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me.